# Can a single bios setting change on its own?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

Dell workstation.  System was up and running.  The site had power fluctuations during the morning.  Decided to shut down the system even though it's protected by a UPS.  Shut down the workstation and it wouldn't reboot: "windows failed to boot"

Found a setting in the bios under General SATA disk operation set to RAID instead of auto detect.  Changed it and it booted successfully.  Can that setting (or any other in the bios) change without human intervention?

Comment: No; Outside of the firmware settings being lost. Replacing the CMOS battery would be my suggestion

Comment: @Ramhound - Disagree, Hardware faults, cosmic radiation, x-ray radiation are possibilities.  I'm sure you know this, and the video is not 100% correct, but https://youtu.be/AaZ_RSt0KP8

Comment: I've seen this happen on several pc"s.

Comment: Thanks all.   Got a new piece of info on this....the user had got a bunch of errors, and I'm assuming they were pre windows boot errors or bios errors.  He changed the cmos battery but it wouldn't boot.  I must assume the low cmos battery state led to the corruption or maybe just put the bios back to default settings and that one setting prevented the disk from being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a single BIOS setting can change on its own!

You typically find a CR2032 battery on mainboards to buffer the BIOS settings.
Once this battery is empty or nearly empty the BIOS cannot properly store its values. This becomes obvious when the BIOS date and time always fall back to a certain moment in the past.

As long as your workstation was powered an empty battery could not cause any negative effects. Permanent power was therefore masking an existing battery failure.
Replacing the battery is recommended to exclude the battery as a reason of failure.